# WPF c# Hangman game : disable wrong letters and show error message and 2 others questions

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok guys here's my code :

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult confirmatBoxResult = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
        "Êtes-vous sûr ?", "Confirmer", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

    if (confirmatBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        {
            char ch = c;
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Content = c;
            btn.Width = 60;
            btn.Height = 60;
            btn.FontSize = 36;

            panel_lettre.Children.Add(btn);
            lookupLetters[ch] = new List<Label>();
            btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnLetter_Click);

            void btnLetter_Click(object sender2, RoutedEventArgs e2)
            {
                if (lookupLetters.TryGetValue(ch, out List<Label> textList))
                {
                    foreach (var el in textList)
                    {
                        el.Content = ch;
                        btn.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var el in textList)
                    {
                        el.Content = ch;
                        btn.IsEnabled = false;
                        // not correct
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (char ch in txtMot.Text)
        {
            Label Lbl = new Label();
            Lbl.Content = ch;
            Lbl.Content = "_";
            Lbl.FontSize = 36;
            Lbl.Width = 30;
            lookupLetters[ch].Add(Lbl);
            panel_label.Children.Add(Lbl);
        }

        btnMotProposé.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

With the dictionnary :

```
public Dictionary<char, List<Label>> lookupLetters = new Dictionary<char, List<Label>>();
```

---

I managed to show the 26 letters of the alphabet.
They all are button, and show dynamically in a label on click through : **btnClick**.

Yet again, an event coming from **btnLetter_Click** is launched once you click on each button.

Here comes the Dictionnary : it override the content of the label, **(_)**, to replace it with the letter of the word being guessed.

---

So basically,

If the word is test :

1. It shows : _ _ _ _
2. Once I click on the correct alphabet letters that are buttons, it shows the word's letters step by step, until all the letters are fully shown.

---

**Here's my questions** :

1. How can I make it that if I click on any letter that don't match in my word, here **test**, it makes the letter disabled, (*btn.IsEnabled = false;*), then cast a *MessageBox.Show("Wrong letter !);* ?
2. If the word is found, it cast a : MessageBox.Show("Well done, you've found the word !)
3. And let's say after 4 attempts, if the user keep casting mistakes, it shows the word being guess?

Comment: btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnLetter_Click);
You should unsubscribe first or subscribe an event handler in the constructor of the class and not on click event. Otherwise it is going to triggered multiple times with each additional subscription.

Comment: @SimonKatanski the event handler assignment is for a brand new button, isn't it? No multiple subscriptions created...

Comment: @RufusL true, my bad. The button lives in a local scope, and its handler doesn't depend on any global variable, which is fine as well.

Comment: You're right indeed, sorry I deleted my previous message it was a mistake !

Comment: I did not read all of your code, but a suggestion is here: do not try to do all work in a single method. try splitting the work on their own methods, like "addButtons", "checkLetters", "refreshLabels" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my crude version of what your looking for:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int MaxAttempts = 4;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnMotPropose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult confirmatBoxResult = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
            "Êtes-vous sûr ?", "Confirmer", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

        var lookupLetters = new Dictionary<char, List<Label>>();

        if (confirmatBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            int attemptCounter = 0;

            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
            {
                char ch = c;
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Content = c;
                btn.Width = 60;
                btn.Height = 60;
                btn.FontSize = 36;

                panel_lettre.Children.Add(btn);
                lookupLetters[ch] = new List<Label>();
                btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnLetter_Click);

                void btnLetter_Click(object sender2, RoutedEventArgs e2)
                {
                    if (lookupLetters.TryGetValue(ch, out List<Label> textList))
                    {
                        attemptCounter++;

                        foreach (var el in textList)
                        {
                            el.Content = ch;
                            btn.IsEnabled = false;
                        }

                        if (!textList.Any())
                        {
                            btn.IsEnabled = false;
                            MessageBox.Show("Wrong letter!");
                        }

                        if (attemptCounter == MaxAttempts)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Max attempts reached!");
                            ShowAnswer(lookupLetters);
                        }

                        if (AreAllLettersUncovered())
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Well done, you've found the word !!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (char ch in txtMot.Text)
            {
                Label Lbl = new Label();                    
                Lbl.Content = "_";
                Lbl.FontSize = 36;
                Lbl.Width = 30;
                lookupLetters[ch].Add(Lbl);
                panel_label.Children.Add(Lbl);
            }

            btnMotPropose.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private bool AreAllLettersUncovered()
    {
        return panel_label.Children.Cast<Label>().All(p => (string)p.Content != "_");
    }

    private void ShowAnswer(Dictionary<char, List<Label>> lookupLetters)
    {
        var lettersWithLabels = lookupLetters.Where(p => p.Value.Any());
        foreach (var letterWithLabel in lettersWithLabels)
        {
            foreach (var label in letterWithLabel.Value)
            {
                label.Content = letterWithLabel.Key.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As side comments - I'd decouple the dynamic on click event handler into a separate method - it would make the code more readable. The main onClick method is quite long and not easily readable. Your naming convention differs from variable too variable (mixed sometimes with underscore, english/non-english). It's easier to read code when the naming convention is unchanging.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take on consideration everything you said and enhance my code.

Thank you !